# sql select data from two tables

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables:

inventory:

```
id, name
1   Computer
```

and sub_inventory:

```
id, name, inventory_id
 5  mouse      1
```

As you can see, there is inventory_id that belongs to id of inventory.

I need to create a select, that will give me this result:

```
id, name, inventory_id, inventory_name
5   mouse      1           computer
```

Comment: Did you do any research? This is SQL 101

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT b.id, a.name, a.inventory_id, b.inventory_name FROM a, b WHERE a.id=b.inventory_id
```

Note that the WHERE clause is what *joins* your 2 tables but you really need to know which are your foreign and primary keys.

Comment: Recommend explicit joins rather than old style implicit joins

Comment: No, just good habits, easier to understand and troubleshoot code, as the complexity increases.